# Is there a way to get all of the font characters from Google Fonts?

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-font-api, google-fonts

It seems that even if I choose all of the languages, I receive the font stripped of characters like ←, →, ⅞, and many others.

I’m aware of the &text=ABC option, but sometimes it is not practical (e. g. if you use a lot of various symbols).

**Example for the “IBM Plex Sans”:**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IBM+Plex+Sans&display=swap&subset=cyrillic,cyrillic-ext,greek,latin-ext,vietnamese');
```

All available subsets are included but still no access to the full character set.

Comment: I'm afraid those are just fonts that don't contain these characters.

Comment: No, some of them do. You can download the font and check.

Comment: Can you give an example of a specific font and of the font-face rule you're using to call it?

Comment: @MrLister Added example.

Comment: Your url indicates which subsets should be fetched. Neither ⅞ nor ←/→ are in any of the sets you're asking for; have you tried not passing a subset argument in order to get the full font?

Comment: You can get these extra glyphs using the `text` query parameter: See also ["Google Fonts - IBM Plex Sans and left/right arrows rendering"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66801221/google-fonts-ibm-plex-sans-and-left-right-arrows-rendering/76526243#76526243) Also it seems google has changed/dropped support for the `subset` parameter in the new API.