# Google Fonts - IBM Plex Sans and left/right arrows rendering

Tags: css, fonts, google-fonts

I use IBM Plex Sans from Google Fonts, but character as left/right arrows are rendered different then others symbols.

Problem appear on Chrome, New Edge, Opera, Safari, Firefox, but Internet Explorer 11 is good.

Image:

[image: Text]

Where is the problem?

Comment: What Unicode characters are you using for these arrows?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the arrows Unicode and add params to the related Google Fonts URL. [Here](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started) is the detailed explanation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the google font API doesn't return the glyphs of this unicode range, albeit supported by IBM Plex.

### Workaround 1: download the "full" font

The google font UI includes a "download family" button to download the complete family as a trutype/ttf font.

You could download these files and load them as a locally hosted font source.

**Drawback:** These files are pretty large due to the less efficient truetype compression.
You could convert them via a tool like [transfonter](https://transfonter.org/) to woff2, but the font will still be pretty huge since it includes all available glyphs.

### Workaround 2: create a custom subset via `&text` query parameter

Fetch the subset including all arrow glyphs like so:

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=IBM+Plex+Sans&text=←↑→↓↔↕↖↗↘↙
```

Output CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/l/font?kit=zYXgKVElMYYaJe8bpLHnCwDKtdPMDmTK4TVtn4n7Y97fmmF-kWzn6TYFtPjVl2q7BmUocg&skey=db4d85f0f9937532&v=v19) format('woff2');
}
```

Now we can add this `@font-face` rule to load the arrow glyphs in addition to the regularly loaded subjsets

```css
/** only arrows */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/l/font?kit=zYXgKVElMYYaJe8bpLHnCwDKtdPMD6au90cJiPqfd667jxAagxqD-kFhpIyxhh_fGB9MbXk&skey=db4d85f0f9937532&v=v19) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+2190-2199;
}


.plex{
  font-size:10vmin;
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=IBM+Plex+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<p class="plex">IBM Plex  &#x2190; &#x2191; &#x2192; &#x2193; &#x2194; &#x2195; &#x2196; &#x2197; &#x2198; &#x2199;</p>
```

Obviously, your font-family must include these glyphs.
Here's an example showing Fira Sans, which only include custom arrows for left,right, down and up.

```css
body{
  font-size:5em;
}


/** only arrows */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/l/font?kit=zYXgKVElMYYaJe8bpLHnCwDKtdPMD6au90cJiPqfd667jxAagxqD-kFhpIyxhh_fGB9MbXk&skey=db4d85f0f9937532&v=v19) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+2190-2199;
  
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Fira Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/l/font?kit=va9E4kDNxMZdWfMOD5VflZrQo7FvltpfdcxE__9bajWcrTZbAYeEiQH32WSGeTxr&skey=6bde03e5f15b0572&v=v17) format('woff2');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-stretch: normal;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/l/font?kit=memSYaGs126MiZpBA-UvWbX2vVnXBbObj2OVZyOOSr4dVJWUgsjZ0C4ie0ncQzny-KClHo_cmBsJhSfL3UJDJude6GUbURQncdQ&skey=62c1cbfccc78b4b2&v=v35) format('woff2');
}



.plex{
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans', sans-serif;
}

.fira{
  font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
}

.openSans{
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!--
-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=IBM+Plex+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

<p class="default">Default unicode characters  &#x2190; &#x2191; &#x2192; &#x2193; &#x2194; &#x2195; &#x2196; &#x2197; &#x2198; &#x2199;</p>

<p class="plex">IBM Plex  &#x2190; &#x2191; &#x2192; &#x2193; &#x2194; &#x2195; &#x2196; &#x2197; &#x2198; &#x2199;</p>

<p class="fira">Fira Sans  &#x2190; &#x2191; &#x2192; &#x2193; &#x2194; &#x2195; &#x2196; &#x2197; &#x2198; &#x2199;</p>
```